# how to open mutliple files tiled vertically on a dual monitor setup

Tags: vbscript

i have a dual monitor setup. i have been working on 4 excel workbooks simultaneously and it is going to continue for a long time.
i wanted to make a batch file or a vb script file to open the required files and tile them vertically on the monitors. 2 files on one monitor and 2 more on the other.
i found this code

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.MinimizeAll
shell.Open "F:\FSA 30-08-15.xlsx"
shell.Open "F:\SMH 09-08-15.xlsx"
shell.Open "F:\MPP 23-08-15.xlsx"
shell.Open "F:\GIP 23-08-15.xlsx"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
shell.TileVertically
```

but this does not open all files nor does it tile them. it only opens the first file. running the script again opens the 2nd file and so on. but tiling the files doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason being you are using one shell object to open multiple Excel workbooks. As a result, only one instance of Excel is created and all 4 workbooks are opened in that Excel instance. You might have to update your script so that each workbook open in separate Excel instance and then you can tile them.

```
Dim shell, objEx

Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.MinimizeAll

Set objEx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objEx.Application.Visible = True
objEx.WorkBooks.Open "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\Work.xlsx"
Set objEx = Nothing

Set objEx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objEx.Application.Visible = True
objEx.WorkBooks.Open "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\portfolioIM_20150729_1318.xlsx"
Set objEx = Nothing

Set objEx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objEx.Application.Visible = True
objEx.WorkBooks.Open "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\Sample Conditional Formatting.xlsx"
Set objEx = Nothing

Set objEx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objEx.Application.Visible = True
objEx.WorkBooks.Open "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\Products.xlsx"
Set objEx = Nothing

Wscript.Sleep 5000
shell.TileVertically
set shell = nothing
```

Comment: just tried this. the files open but stay hidden. i can see them in task manager but they do not show anywhere else.

Comment: It worked when I tried.....Are you sure you are using correct file names and paths?

Comment: Maybe the files that you are trying to open are too big and the sleep isn't enough. Try to open smaller files and see what is the problem. And before that, kill all Excel processes.

Comment: tried with smaller files. files from different location. files with .csv format. but excel still stays in the background

Comment: is the dual monitor setup causing this?